# How to detect visible text in a text field in a PDF?

Tags: pdfbox

When using PDFBox to populate a text field in a form in a PDF, it is possible that the text overflows the text field and is not visible when opening the PDF in a viewer.

**Question:** Is it possible to use PDFBox to detect how much text within a text field is visible?

---

At the risk of falling victim to an XY problem, here is the context in which this came up.

I have a PDF which is provided by the Danish government, and the software I am creating needs to be able to fill out this form programmatically. On pages 5 and 6 of this document, there is a large blank area that needs to be filled out. The way the PDF creators designed it, they just made two text fields (named Text57 and Text58), which a person directly filling out the form would manually need to jump between.

The problem is, I need to be able to populate these fields with text, and if the text is too large to fit in the first text field, then it needs to overflow into the second text field. However, I do not seem to have any way of actually detecting when the text overflows in the first text field.

One workaround which could be acceptable, would be if I could modify the document to remove the second text field, and just have the first text field span multiple pages, but while playing around in Acrobat, this does not seem to be possible.

The PDF in question can be found here: https://www.trafikstyrelsen.dk/~/media/Dokumenter/10%20Bolig/Bolig/Private%20lejeboliger/Lejekontrakt/typeformular-a.pdf

Here is a code snippet which populates the problematic field with 100 lines numbered from 1 to 100.

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("typeformular-a.pdf"));
PDField text57 = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("Text57");
text57.setValue(IntStream.range(1, 101).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
document.save("typeformular-a.out.pdf");
```

After the code is run, we can see that the text gets cut off after line 44. Of course I cannot simply count lines in my text, because under normal circumstances the lines in the text will wrap, which would invalidate that approach.

**Auxiliary question:** Is there any other approach that could solve this original problem of splitting text across multiple pages?

Comment: "just have the first text field span multiple pages" does not exist. But your question is a very valid one... at this time, the only idea I have would be that you clone PlainTextFormatter.java and modify it so that it tells whether it would fit or not.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is the `PlainTextFormatter` already used to create appearances for text form field widgets?

Comment: @mkl Yes it is called in AppearanceGeneratorHelper.

Comment: I am also wondering, whether it would make sense to add some method into PDFBox that tells whether a text fits into the field widget(s) or not. (It is easy for a single-line field, but not for multi-line field)